# How to create relationships with SQLite (Foreign key)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite

I'm trying to create relationships with my tables in SQLite (I'm currently working with Xamarin.Forms), but I'm not getting the expected result, adding the Data Annotations   `[ForeignKey(typeof(UserLocal))]` 
But I'm not creating the relationship in my BD, what's going on? my BD is only doing the indexed relationships, but it is not relating them to foreign keys

[Browser SQLite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9rFf.png)

For the connection to my database, I created an interface which gets the route in Android and iOS, and then to manage my INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc ... I do it from the DataService.CS service.

ANDROID:

```cs
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PathService))]
namespace AppValora.Droid.Implementation
{
    public class PathService : IPathService
    {
        public string GetDatabasePath()
        {              
            string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            var directoryPath = Path.Combine(path, "Valora/Databases");
            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                try
                {

                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            return Path.Combine(directoryPath, "Valora.db3");
        }
    }
}
```

iOS:

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PathService))]
namespace AppValora.iOS.Implementation
{
    public class PathService : IPathService
    {
        public string GetDatabasePath()
        {
            string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string libFolder = Path.Combine(docFolder, "..", "Library");

            if (!Directory.Exists(libFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(libFolder);
            }

            return Path.Combine(libFolder, "Valora.db3");
        }
    }
}
```

DATASERVICE.CS:

```cs
#region Servicios
private SQLiteAsyncConnection connection;
private DialogService dialogService;       
#endregion

#region Constructor
public DataService()
{
    dialogService = new DialogService();
    OpenOrCreateDB();
}
#endregion

private async Task OpenOrCreateDB()
{
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage);

    if (status != Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync((Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage)))
        {
            await dialogService.ShowMessage("!ATENCIÓN!", "Valora necesita el permiso de archivos para este proceso.");
        }

        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync((Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage));
        //Best practice to always check that the key exists
        if (results.ContainsKey(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage))
            status = results[Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage];
    }

    if (status == Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        //CONSULTO PATH
        var databasePath = DependencyService.Get<IPathService>().GetDatabasePath();
        //CREO LA CONEXION
        this.connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);
        //CREACION DE TABLAS
        await connection.CreateTableAsync<UserLocal>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await connection.CreateTableAsync<Companie>().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    else if (status != Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Unknown)
    {

    }    

    public async Task Insert<T>(T model)
    {
        await this.connection.InsertAsync(model);
    }
}
```

The DataService in addition to making the connection creates the tables in which I want to generate the relationship, The data model are the following...

USERLOCAL.CS:

```cs
public class UserLocal
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IdLogin { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }             
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Rut { get; set; }
    public bool Recordado { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]
    public List<Companie> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

COMPANIE.CS:

```cs
public class Companie
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IdLogin { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public bool Principal { get; set; }
    public bool ExternalCorp { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorporate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(UserLocal))]
    public int IdUser { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public UserLocal UserLocal { get; set; }
}
```

Next, the code of how to insert the records in my tables is shown below, I think it is in this part where I am wrong, since I am not able to create the relationships

VIEWMODEL.CS:

```cs
ListaCompanie.Clear();          

// I WALK THE NUMBER OF COMPANIES THAT I WANT TO ADD
foreach (var item in loginResponse.Companies)
{
    var companie = new Companie
    {
        IdLogin = item.Id,
        Nombre = item.Name,
        ExternalCorp = item.ExternalCorp,
        IsCorporate = item.IsCorporate,
        Principal = item.Principal,
        //CLAVE FORANEA
        IdUser = loginResponse.Id,
    };

    ListaCompanie.Add(companie);

    await dataService.Insert(companie);
}

var user = new UserLocal
{
        IdLogin = loginResponse.Id,
        Nombre = loginResponse.Name,
        Recordado = Settings.Recordado,
        Rut = loginResponse.Rut,
        Token = loginResponse.Token,
        Password = GetSHA1(Settings.Password),
        Companies = ListaCompanie,
};

await dataService.Insert(user);
```

Why are these relationships not generated? How can I relate my tables to SQLite? what am I doing wrong? I am working with Xamarin.Forms with an MVVM architectural pattern, any help for me?

Comment: As I can check are you want  to achieve this through code first aproch is it true?

Comment: yes sr! @Avinash

Comment: You deleted your latest question before I could press "Post Answer". :(

Comment: My answer is to that question is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3DHjZB) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [SQLite.Net.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/) for creating the relationships then you need to set the `CascadeOperations` like so:

```cs
public class UserLocal
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdLogin { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }             
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Rut { get; set; }
    public bool Recordado { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // THIS BIT HERE 
    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<Companie> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

The other thing is if you are using this library then you can `insertWithChildren` to create the relationship like so:

```cs
var user = new UserLocal
{
    IdLogin = loginResponse.Id,
    Nombre = loginResponse.Name,
    Recordado = Settings.Recordado,
    Rut = loginResponse.Rut,
    Token = loginResponse.Token,
    Password = GetSHA1(Settings.Password),
    Companies = ListaCompanie,
};

// I WALK THE NUMBER OF COMPANIES THAT I WANT TO ADD
foreach (var item in loginResponse.Companies)
{
    var companie = new Companie
    {
        IdLogin = item.Id,
        Nombre = item.Name,
        ExternalCorp = item.ExternalCorp,
        IsCorporate = item.IsCorporate,
        Principal = item.Principal,
        //CLAVE FORANEA
        UserLocal = user,
        // You dont need to set this as it will be assigned in InsertWithChildren
        // IdUser = loginResponse.Id,
    };

    ListaCompanie.Add(companie);

    await dataService.InsertWithChildren(companie);
}
```

Comment: Your explanation seems logical and appropriate, but when invoking the Insert with children method in my data service, it can not be invoked, how can I build it? IntelliSense does not suggest anything to me, any complement to your answer?

Comment: `InsertWithChildren` is part of the Sqlite.net.Extensions. You can read more about it here https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/overview. If you are using it then you will need to add the using `using SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions;` or `using SQLiteNetExtensionsAsync.Extensions;`

Comment: Your answer, I only fill the Companie table and with its foreign key (IdUser = 0), the UserLocal table is not filling it ... any recommendations to approve your answer?  @Ian Smith