# How to add/ load/ delete items from a foreign key table in xamarin forms with sqlite-net-pcl and sqliteExtensions

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-pcl

Hi i have this two tables ( not sure if they are written correctly) an agenda can contain many Tasks, my question is how do i write the methods to  add/delete/load my tasks in my agenda, i am not sure how this work when you have a foreign key ? Thank you.

**Agenda.cs in the Models folder**

```
    [Table("Agenda")]
    public class Agenda
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Topic { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; } 
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
}
```

**Tasks.cs in Models folder**

```
[Table("Task")]
public class Tasks
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Agenda))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne]
    public Agenda Agenda { get; set; }
    
}
```

**AgendaDatabase.cs in the Database folder ( all my operation currently for the Agenda table)**

```
public class AgendaDatabase
{
    
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public AgendaDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
       
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<Agenda>().Wait();
    


    }

    // Get all agenda
    public Task<List<Agenda>> GetAgendasAsync()
    {

        return database.Table<Agenda>().ToListAsync();
    }

    // Get specific agenda
    public Task<Agenda> GetAgendaAsync(int id)
    {
        return database.Table<Agenda>()
                        .Where(i => i.ID == id)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    // Insert new agenda (save)
    public Task<int> SaveAgendaAsync(Agenda agenda)
    {
        if (agenda.ID != 0)
        {
            return database.UpdateAsync(agenda);
        }
        else
        {
            return database.InsertAsync(agenda);
        }
    }
    
    //Delete specific agenda
    public Task<int> DeleteAgendaAsync(Agenda agenda)
    {
        return database.DeleteAsync(agenda);
    }
    public Task<int> AddAgendaAsync(Agenda agenda)
    {
        return database.InsertAsync(agenda);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/

Comment: I read this, but i'm not sure it makes sens to me on how to implement it in my context.

Comment: @Jason would it be possible to have an example please, i am stuck with that also when i use the WithChildren it's not recognized.