# SQLite VIsual Studios Referencing an object in a table

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

I have created two models and created a table for each. I also have a view for each. In my person view, I have a collection view of Cars, when I create a person I assign them a Car object. My object is being passed to the person fine, but when I go to save I get an error that says "Don't know about People.Person.Cars".

How do I set up my Person model Table to accept an object.

```
using SQLite;

namespace People.Models
{
    //sets table for people
    [Table("people")]
    public class Person
    {
        //key, with autoincrement
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }


        //max length and unique entry
        [MaxLength(50), Unique]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Cars employeeCar { get; set; }


    }
}
```

```
using SQLite;

namespace People.Models
{
    //sets table for people
    [Table("people")]
    public class Person
    {
        //key, with autoincrement
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }


        //max length and unique entry
        [MaxLength(50), Unique]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Cars employeeCar { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: use https://github.com/media-tools/sqlite-net-extensions

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55573511/199364, or https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+.net+sqlite+table+relationships